# Elasticsearch::UnsupportedProductError (The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Getting this error when using searchkick with elasticsearch on mac.

Searchkick version: searchkick (4.5.2)

```
$ elasticsearch --version
warning: no-jdk distributions that do not bundle a JDK are deprecated and will be removed in a future release
Version: 7.10.2-SNAPSHOT, Build: oss/tar/unknown/2021-01-16T01:41:27.115673Z, JVM: 16.0.2
```

To reproduce

Product.reindex

Comment: Try downgrading your `elasticsearch` gem e.g. add `gem  elasticsearch, "< 7.14"` to your Gemfile. It seems that 7.14 introduced these issues. [Open Issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/1429)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It worked fine after degrading to elastic search < 7.14. So basically added a gem to restrict the version upgrade

```
gem  elasticsearch, "< 7.14"
```

Comment: I was having the same issue with fluentd elasticsearch-plugin , as suggested in here ,I did the gem downgrade and got my issue fixed ... I guess this problem is common across all elasticsearch clients

Comment: Discussion in details to why this is: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/1429

Answer (score 35):

If you are using Python elasticsearch client, you need to downgrade or install version before 7.14.0.

```
pip install elasticsearch<7.14.0
```

Comment: See more detail about this here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/pull/1623 shocking, intentionally breaking move from elasticsearch, I'll be pushing to move our clusters to opensearch

Comment: related to this are discussion in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1639 and https://github.com/toptal/chewy/pull/811/files

Comment: worked for me


pip3 install elasticsearch==7.13.4

Answer (score 1):

`Elasticsearch::UnsupportedProductError` is raised when your Elasticsearch server version don't match with Ruby's Elasticsearch client (`gem elasticsearch`). In order to fix this properly you need a server that is up to date with latest Elasticsearch (ES) releases

that means if you are on ES provider like https://cloud.elastic.co/ where you work with latest versions of cluster it's easy peasy => server gets upgraded => this is not an issue

if you however work with provider that is slow to catch up with latest ES releases (like AWS Elasticsearch / AWS Opensearch where last version is 7.10 and will not get upgraded anytime soon) your only option is to use `gem  elasticsearch, "< 7.14"` (Siddhant's [answer in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68952974/473040) ...and yes this means no potential security updates

other solution may be to silence the verification by overriding method [verify_with_version_or_header](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/7.17/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch.rb#L70) as proposed in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/1429#issuecomment-958162468

but reality is both of this solutions are just "not recommended" workarounds. The real fix is a server upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Bypass the check with a monkeypatch. For example in Rails:

```rb
# in config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb

module Elasticsearch
  class Client
    alias original_verify_with_version_or_header verify_with_version_or_header

    def verify_with_version_or_header(...)
      original_verify_with_version_or_header(...)
    rescue Elasticsearch::UnsupportedProductError => exception
      warn("Ignoring elasticsearch complaint: #{exception.message}")
    end
  end
end
```